# Sql Query combine using Top and Ascending order

Tags: sql

I have been creating sql query as shown below :

```
 select * from (select DISTINCT * from (select po.tGroup_id,pp.tGroup_id   as GroupID from tPhos_Line_Operator PO
LEFT join tPhos_Line_Parameter PP
on PO.tGroup_id = PP.tGroup_id) A) Ac
left JOIN 
(SELECT top 1 tGroup_id FROM tGROUP_LOG  order by id desc) B
on  Ac.tGroup_id = B.tGroup_id
```

I was expecting to see records like in the image below :

[image]

But I keep getting this records :

[image]

I tried to hardcode in the left join by putting the **tGroup_id=29** and it work as I got the exact record I want. Refer to first image.

```
select * from (select DISTINCT * from (select po.tGroup_id,pp.tGroup_id as GroupID from tPhos_Line_Operator PO
LEFT join tPhos_Line_Parameter PP
on PO.tGroup_id = PP.tGroup_id) A) Ac
left JOIN 
(SELECT top 1 tGroup_id FROM tGROUP_LOG where tGroup_id = 29 order by id desc 
) B
on  Ac.tGroup_id = B.tGroup_id
```

I do not want to hardcode it.
Can someone tell me where did I missed out or did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the left table (AC), with the matching rows in the right table (tGROUP_LOG). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

Comment: I have edit the question.

Comment: You're using product specific SQL. Please tag the dbms used!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way, instead of using top 1, I can use max.

```
SELECT max(id) as TESTID,tGroup_id FROM tGROUP_LOG 
group by tGroup_id
```

I consider this has fixed my issue. Thanks